# Docker Authentication Private Git Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to include some files from a private git repository thru the ADD command in my dockerfile since it supports URL as source.

But I dont know how to set the authentication.
I am getting forwarded into the login page so when the image is created. It is the login page of the git repository.

```
FROM myimage
ARG version
LABEL Name="sample" Version="$version"

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/configs
ADD <private git> /tmp/configs
```

Any hints?

Comment: What kind of auth?

Comment: I admittedly haven't tried this, but if you're using the ssh url, i would think it would use your credentials. If that doesn't work, setup another user in github, generate a key pair for this user, and give them access to the repo. Then COPY the private key file into the docker container.

Comment: Its just a list of files from another git repository that I need to include in my docker image.  Apparently when you run the ADD command to a GIT URL, the login page is being sent back to you.  So instead of the files that you are expecting, you are getting the login page of your GIT repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ADD` can't be used to clone repository. It only downloads direct file links.

But you can clone your repository before building an image.

1. Specify in Dockerfile what you want to add from the repo.

   FROM myimage

   RUN mkdir -p /tmp/configs

   ADD repo_root/inner_dir /tmp/configs
2. Clone the repository and build an image.

   $(git clone git@***.git) && docker build . ; $(rm -rf repo_root)

This will clone the repository, build an image and delete repository directory.